# regexp on compressed files in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to do some regexp on path names and keep it.

My lines to test are like :

`"/home/tclshell/test.tcl.gz"
"/home/tclshell/test1.tcl"
/home/tclshell/test.tcl`

so It triied things like :
`regexp {(\S+\.tcl(?:\.gz)?)} $line blank mypath`
or
`regexp {(\S+\.tcl(|\.gz))} $line blank mypath`

But it don't seems to work, the `"` seems to be kept in `$mypath`.
What's wrong in the regexp ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If there is an optional `"` at the beginning, add it - `"?(\S+\.tcl(?:\.gz)?)`

Comment: my expected output is `/home/tclshell/test.tcl.gz` for the first line line for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that `\S` matches any character but whitespace, so it also matches `"`.

You may add an optional `"` at the start of the pattern but ouside of the capturing group - `"?(\S+\.tcl(?:\.gz)?)`:

```
set line "\"/home/tclshell/test.tcl.gz\""
regexp {"?(\S+\.tcl(?:\.gz)?)} $line blank mypath
puts $mypath
```

See [Tcl online demo](https://ideone.com/L4T1pg)

Another way is to exclude the `"` from `\S` by replacing it with a negated character class with reverse shorthand class for whitespace (`\s`) and adding the `"` into it: `[^\s"]`:

```
([^\s"]+\.tcl(?:\.gz)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OPQoRF/1)

Comment: Note that this regex (like the one used by the OP) will match a lot of things that may not be desired, such as `?#&=@.tcl.foo`.

Comment: Sure, it will as `[^\s"]+` matches 1+ chars other than whitespace and a double quote, but that seems irrelevant.